# SyntaxError - unexcepted ")"

Tags: ruby, error-handling, syntax-error

I am beginner to ruby. I want to fix mistake in one of mailing software. Code with fixes I appiled is below:

```
@headers[:recipient] = {
      "To" => (cc.map do |p| 
            if not p.full_address == "mail@fake.sender.example.com"
                p.full_address 
        end),
      "Cc" => [],
    }
```

Unfortunately, that gives my these errors:

```
home/tymon/mmm/lib/mmm/modes/reply_mode.rb:103: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
        end),
            ^
/home/tymon/mmm/lib/mmm/modes/reply_mode.rb:104: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end
      "Cc" => [],
```

I do not know the reasons of them. I read Ruby documentation about blocks and it should work well. Please suggest me something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `end)` is allowed.  It needs to be one it's own line or at least have a semicolon after it.  I'd be more inclined to use braces though:

```
@headers[:recipient] = {
  "To" => (cc.map { |p|
      if not p.full_address == "mail@fake.sender.example.com"
      p.full_address
      }),
  "Cc" => [],
}
```

And I'd probably change your logic to the inline version and compact it to avoid any nil entries:

```
@headers[:recipient] = {
  "To" => (cc.map { |p| p.full_address == "mail@fake.sender.example.com" ? nil : p.full_address}.compact),
  "Cc" => [],
}
```

**Update**  As @sawa mentioned '(begin; end)' is valid.  Looking at it again I realize it's complaining because the 'if' isn't 'end'ed.

```
@headers[:recipient] = {
  "To" => (cc.map do |p|
        if not p.full_address == "mail@fake.sender.example.com"
          p.full_address
        end
      end),
  "Cc" => [],
}
```

Still, I like my middle style best.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `(begin; end)` is grammatical.

Comment: @sawa - good to know.  OP - Now that I stare at it more it's because you don't have an 'end' for your 'if'.  Still, I like my last style best :)